# Retrieving list of all variables inside a web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

This is a followup to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083313/web-workers-and-canvas-data/23083918?), and my code is similar to the one in the accepted answer.

I'm making a site that teaches programming for beginners and I would like to make some kind of automated testing run after the student has run the code to see if the their variables are defined, have correct values and so on. In other words, I would need something like `this`, but sending it as an added `postMessage()` message gives me `[object global]`. I also can't use `window` since it doesn't exist in that scope.

Example: the user writes the code

`var name = "somename";
var age = 25;`

should return an array or object that has `["name": "somename", "age": 25]`

http://pastebin.com/S1xxds43

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype[methodName] = function() {
    var self = this;
    postMessage({called: methodName, args: arguments, currentObjectAttributes: self});
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you: your first code is the same as what I have now. Where do I pass `Object.keys(self)`? I have updated the question with a pastebin to my current code.

Comment: No it's not. I can't run your code so this is just speculation, but it looks like your `postMessage` method is defined in outer scope, and when you invoke it, `this` (aka the current context) is going to be the global object. If you want the context of `this` to be the instance of a canvas, you need to save that context in a var like `self` so that you can pass in the correct object.
Also, because you are passing in the entire object as "currentObjectAttributes", I figured you may only want the attributes of the `self` object. You would access an array of those attributes with `Object.keys`.

Comment: It's important to note that `this` is defined as the context only at the time of invocation. That object that you are passing into `postMessage` doesn't actually exist until `postMessage` gets invoked, and it's only at that moment that the value and context for `this` is evaluated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm confusing you or I'm making myself confused because I'm not quite sure what his function does (Javascript is not my primary language to work with). In either case I'm sorry.

What I would like is to have an editor and let the user write some code, let's say `var name = "someName"; var age = 25;`. The user clicks a button to run the code, and this starts the web worker. When the worker has finished, i.e. the exit message is sent, have the value of those variables returned. It doesn't have to be in the context of a Canvas.

Comment: If I use your code, nothing gets drawn on the Canvas, although the other functions are working. I tried doing `postMessage(['exit', Object.keys(self)])`, but it seems like it returns only the names of the variables, not the values of them.

Comment: Sorry for the many comments. I tried:

`var codeWithMessagesAndExit = codeWithMessages + "\n\n\ \
var userDefinedVars = Object.keys(self).map(function (key) { \n\
    return self[key]; \n\
});\n\
  postMessage(['exit', userDefinedVars]);";`

but I get `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': An object could not be cloned. `